# clone php foreach elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, foreach, clone

I got a `foreach` that generates a list of links now in the top right corner of every link I got a clone button that when clicked should clone that element. The below code in its current format.

```
    <?php
      foreach ($result as $value) {
        list($classname, $origin, $name) = explode('_', $value);
        $classname = trim($classname, '[]');
        $origin    = trim($origin, '[]');
        $name      = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        echo "<li class='audiofile " . $name . " " . $classname . "' id='" . $value . "'>".
                "<a class='btn_clone' id='' onclick='repeat()'>#</a>".
                "<a href='" . $directoryname . "/" . $value . "'>".
                  "<img src='images/avatars/" . $classname . ".jpg'>".
                  "<div class='audiotext'>".
                    "<span class='audiotitle'>" . $name . "</span>".
                    "<span class='audioorigin'>" . $origin .  "</span>".
                  "</div>".
                "</a>".
              "</li>";
      }
    ?>
```

This goes together with this js further down the file.

```
    var i = 0;
    var original = document.getElementById('<?php echo $value ?>');

    function repeat() {
      var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
      clone.id = "clone" + ++i;
      original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }
```

Currently it will clone only the last item of the list no matter what item you clicked the clone button. And that is I think because the `$value` used for the var `original` is simply the last item of the `foreach`.

So how to make it work with the generated id's in the `foreach`. Or if there is another way to make each item clone but keeping the `foreach` intact I would really appreciate it to hear it. Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the element by usin `this.parentElement` when the click event occurs:

```
var j = 0;
function repeat(event) {
    var original = event.target.parentNode;
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "clone" + ++j;
    original.parentElement.appendChild(clone);
}
```

And you have to add the `event` in your `onclick` attribute:

```
//.......
"<a class='btn_clone' id='' onclick='repeat(event)'>#</a>".
//.......                                   ^ add this
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: How would I make this into the function repeat? I am trying now but get a few errors like original not defined. Thanks so much for helping btw! I used this. https://jsfiddle.net/z4dkaz1u/ 
Now testing the revised code. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Just tested your latest revised code and it ain't giving a error but it ain't cloning either.

Comment: Sorry my bad please just remove `var original = document.getElementById('<?php echo $value ?>');` and use the code in the answer !

Comment: I am sure i am doing it wrong somehow. Really appreciate you taking the time to help me on this. I got it now like this: https://jsfiddle.net/no2vv2vp/

Comment: I've added that to prevent the URL from changing the page but since your URL doesn't have an Href attribute you can remove that ;)

Comment: Please update your code to my answer and let me know if it achieves your goal ;)

Comment: I am getting now: cannot read property 'clonenode' of undefined https://jsfiddle.net/no2vv2vp/1/

Comment: I just did and added the event part but get the same error :-( shall we go to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117977/discussion-between-ismail-rbouh-and-purple11111).